# R - Forecasting - Predicting monthly values based on previous year

Tags: r, regression, forecasting

Not sure if this is the right place to post this but here we are.

I have data points for each month in 2017, and for each month in 2018 up until (and including) July. I want to predict data values for August and September of 2018, based on the previous months of 2018, and August and September of 2017.

I'm hoping to write this as a script in R, but I have no idea where to start. I have basic skills in R, but have not done forecasting before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is a starter: [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.org/fpp2/)

Comment: I'd have a look at [prophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/); the documentation makes it quite easy to get started.